# Error while assigning Swift delegate to Objective-C object

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is my Swift class :

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
    public var inAppMessagesController: MPInAppMessagesController!

fun myFunction() {
    self.inAppMessagesController.inAppInteractionDelegate = self    // Error in this line - Cannot assign value of type 'MyClass' to type 'MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate?'
}

}  

extension MyClass : MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate {
  // Functions 
}
```

As stated in comments, this is the error -

> Cannot assign value of type 'MyClass' to type
>   'MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate?'

**inAppInteractionDelegate** in `Objective-C` class **MPInAppMessagesController** :

```
@interface MPInAppMessagesController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate> inAppInteractionDelegate;

@end
```

**MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate** declared in **MPInAppMessagesController.h** :

```
@protocol MPInAppMessageControllerDelegate<NSObject>

// Functions

@end
```

Comment: For me your code is working fine. Make your code clean , delete derived data, restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

The only missing part is you need to include this class inside the bridging file

```
#import "MPInAppMessagesController.h"
```

Look here to a [SwiftObjc](https://github.com/ShKhan9/SwiftObjc2)